# PyQt5 - QPushButton.pressed() signal/slot is not updating a QLabel widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, signals-slots

This is my first question on here as a fairly new Python and Qt programmer.  I have tried to find a solution, but not had much luck (I may just be phrasing the question incorrectly).

I have produced the following code which will hopefully help demonstrate my issue:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.resize(410, 131)
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")

        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.gridLayout)

        self.mainButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Main", self)
        self.altButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Alt", self)
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Main/Alt", self)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Label", self)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.mainButton, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.altButton, 0, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 3)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton, 1, 0)


def setMain():
    print("Main is chosen")
    ui.label.setText("Main is chosen")
    # ui.label.update()

def setAlt():
    print("Alt is chosen")
    ui.label.setText("Alt is chosen")
    # ui.label.update()

def setToggle(btn):
    if btn.isChecked():
        setMain()
    else:
        setAlt()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
ui = MainWindow()

ui.mainButton.pressed.connect(lambda: setMain())
ui.altButton.pressed.connect(lambda: setAlt())
ui.radioButton.toggled.connect(lambda: setToggle(ui.radioButton))

ui.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I run the code above, the "Main" and "Alt" buttons do not update the QLabel widget as I'd expect.  However, the QRadioButton seems to work correctly.

I have found that if I adjust the window size between button presses, the label re-draws itself.  If I used the QButton.clicked() signal instead of the QButton.pressed() signal, the label then updates around 80% of the time.  As you will hopefully see in the console, the functions are invoked by both types of signal/slot consistently, it just seems to be the re-draw of the QLabel widget that is affected.

Everywhere I've looked suggests this should work, so I'm a bit confused.  I'm running Python 3.5 in PyCharm IDE on Mac OSX 10.14.2.  Any help explaining this behaviour and how to overcome it would be greatly appreciated.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So after exploring the broader "Qt Mac OSX redraw bugs" route, I found this: <https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68521>
Despite running Qt5.12.1, it seems this still isn't fixed, but there is a suggestion that more fixes are coming in Qt5.12.2 very soon.  In the meantime, I found that using a QLabel.repaint() method seems to be a workaround.  I'd be interested to hear if anyone has anything more definitive or is sharing the same experience with PyQt 5.12 on Mac OSX.  I have to say... I didn't expect to find a bug this easily after only playing around with the basics.

Comment: Finding a bug like this is just dumb luck. Qt is a huge and complex cross-platform library, so it would be utterly amazing if you never encountered one. Fortunately, Qt is well-maintained, so most bugs will get fixed eventually (just like this one has).

Comment: Indeed.  Unfortunately it still hasn't been fixed in 5.12.1 for me, which seems contrary to what others have reported, but I'll wait until 5.12.2 before exploring any further.

Comment: Actually, it seems I misread the versions. It ***was*** fixed in 5.11.2 (according to [QTBUG-68740](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68740)), but there has since been a regression: see [PYSIDE-695](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-695).